# How to interpret regression coefficient when adjusting for baseline

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, inference, medicine

I want to estimate the effects of sex on sodium level at follow-up after starting treatment with a thiazide (diuretic medication).

The cohort consists of persons starting thiazide treatment. Follow up is until first sodium test after treament initiation.

We model this using linear regression as:

*follow-up sodium ~ sex + baseline sodium*

Adjusting for baseline means the resulting estimate for sex corresponds to change in sodium level at follow-up compared to baseline.

My question is: How should the coefficient for sex then be interpreted?

More specifically, since sex is present at baseline, the baseline sodium will already reflect the effect of sex (women have slightly lower sodium levels compared to men) on sodium level, so:

Q1) Does this mean that the coefficient for sex (when adjusted for baseline sodium) represents the *interaction* between sex and thiazide treatment (ie a supra-additive effect)?

Q2) If Q1 is true, and I then model a multiplicative interaction between thiazide treatment * sex (in this case using a cohort also including persons starting a comparator medication), how is the resulting coefficient thiazide*sex interpreted considering Q1?

Best wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to write out the full equations of the models implied by the standard formula shorthand.

*Model 1*

For Q1, restricted to those taking thiazide:

$$\sf{Na_{fu}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \sf{S} + \beta_2 \sf{Na_{bl}} + \epsilon.$$

Here $\sf{Na}$ is the sodium concentration at follow-up (fu) or baseline (bl), $\sf{S}$ is a variable taking the value 0 for the reference level of Sex (say, female) and 1 for the other level (male), the $\beta_i$ are the regression coefficients to be estimated, and $\epsilon$ is residual error.

The coefficient $\beta_0$, the intercept, is the estimated value of $\sf{Na_{fu}}$ when $\sf{Na_{bl}}=0$ for females. In this model, the (fu-bl) difference for females is thus included as *part of* $\beta_0$. Interpreting this as due to thiazide requires an assumption that nothing else contributes to (fu-bl) differences. Even with that assumption, you'd have to do some more calculations to untangle thiazide from other contributions to $\beta_0$, as $\beta_0$ is for a theoretical but physiologically impossible situation where $\sf{Na_{bl}}$=0.

The coefficient $\beta_2$ represents an additive contribution to the follow-up value, proportional to the baseline value, that is assumed to be the same proportion for both females and males.

The coefficient $\beta_1$ for this first model is just *how much greater*  $\sf{Na_{fu}}$ is for a male than for a female *when they both had the same* $\sf{Na_{bl}}$. It wouldn't be correct to call this an "interaction" in the technical sense; it's just how much more of a difference in sodium there was for men versus women, other things equal. Interpretation in terms of thiazide requires an untested assumption that no other factor contributes to male-female (fu-bl) differences.

*Model 2*

For Q2 with a true sex/treatment interaction, the model is:

$$\sf{Na_{fu}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \sf{S} + \beta_2 \sf{Na_{bl}} + \beta_3 \sf{T}+ \beta_4 \sf{ST}+\epsilon.$$

where $\sf{T}$ is 0 for controls and 1 for the thiazide group.

Now the intercept $\beta_0$ is as above for the *control group* females, $\beta_1$ is the male-female difference at follow-up for the *control group*, and $\beta_3$ is the difference associated with thiazide *for females*. The coefficient $\beta_2$ for baseline sodium is assumed the same for both sexes and treatment groups.

This model provides direct tests for drug-independent (fu-bl) differences between males and females ($\beta_1$). With control-group (fu-bl) differences for females now included in $\beta_0$, the value of $\beta_3$ can be interpreted directly as the effect of thiazide on sodium for females.

The interaction coefficient $\beta_4$ in model 2 is the male-female *difference* associated with thiazide. So $\beta_4$ in this second model is logically similar to $\beta_1$ in the first model, *provided that* there is no male-female difference in (fu-bl) other than due to thiazide.* In that sense I suppose that you could consider $\beta_1$ in the first model a type of "interaction" but that use of the terminology in the first model wouldn't be standard. Calling $\beta_1$ in model 1 an "interaction" will at best tend to confuse others.

*Importance of control group*

Including the control group provides an important advantage in interpreting the results. Any non-thiazide (fu-bl) differences for females are accounted for in $\beta_0$ and (fu-bl) male-female differences other than due to thiazide are accounted for by $\beta_1$. With the control group, $\beta_3$ can be interpreted as the thiazide-associated difference for females, and $\beta_4$ as the (male-female) difference specifically associated with thiazide.

*Other models*

In a comment you ask how the interpretation of these coefficients would change if the baseline sodium term were removed and baseline sodium itself were associated with sex. When you write out the full model you can pursue such possibilities yourself with simple algebraic manipulations and a bit of thought.

Say that baseline sodium is associated with sex in the following linear model:

$$ \sf{Na_{bl}} =\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \sf{S} .$$

Here $\gamma_0$ is the baseline sodium for females and $\gamma_1$ is the (male-female) difference in that value. Then just substitute that relationship into the equation above for model 2 and get:

*Model 3*

$$\sf{Na_{fu}} = (\beta_0 +\beta_2 \gamma_0) + (\beta_1  + \beta_2 \gamma_1) \sf{S} + \beta_3 \sf{T}+ \beta_4 \sf{ST}+\epsilon.$$

The intercept now includes a contribution from the baseline sodium for females and the coefficient for sex includes a contribution from the (male-female) baseline difference. Each of these contributions is weighted by the original $\beta_2$ coefficient. The same approach can elucidate what would happen in other scenarios.

*Better baseline adjustment*

Your way of "adjusting for baseline" assumes that there is an additive contribution to the follow-up value that is proportional to the baseline value. with the same proportionality constant $\beta_2$ for all individuals regardless of sex or treatment group. That's probably not the best way to do that adjustment. Better approaches could be a [repeated-measures analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design) or a [mixed model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) with baseline values taken as a random effect. But the interpretation of the coefficients for $\sf{S,T}$ and $\sf{ST}$ in models 1 and 2, with their implicit assumptions that baseline sodium is unrelated to sex or treatment, would be the same.

---

*Even if that assumption is true, the estimates of these coefficients will differ in practice as the second model includes information from the control cases as well.

Comment: Thank you @EdM for a great answer! I would conclude that the first model is preferable  for the aim of testing whether there is an "interaction" between sex and thiazide use, since it is more parsimonious and does not necessitate a control group without thiazide treatment. Also, would not adjusting for Na-bl in the second model collide with the interaction that is estimated in B4ST, since B1S in that case already represents an "interaction"?

Comment: @Erik omitting controls is ill-advised as then you don't know whether (fu-bl) differences are drug-related or time-related: maybe not a big problem with serum sodium, but critical in other contexts. In model 2 the Na-bl term includes neither S nor T, so there is no "collision." Adding control cases improves the precision of estimates of all the regression coefficients, approximately by the square root of the _total_ number of cases. Parsimony is often over-rated in any event; [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) can be a much larger problem.

Comment: @Erik I expanded the answer to show in more detail just what the control group adds to the analysis. Also, do consider a different way to "adjust for baseline," as recommended in the last paragraph of the answer. I don't think that your model does quite what you want for this adjustment. Might not make a big difference with serum sodium where values are necessarily restricted to a small range, but in other applications it could pose problems. There are well-accepted ways to use repeated-measures or mixed models to adjust for baseline in ways that are easier to interpret.

Comment: I take your point @EdM that other methods may be more appropriate, though I think the questions above remain, so it is valuable to try to answer them. Thanks again for your excellent contribution! As you say, in model 2 the N-bl term does not formally include S, but in reality sex influences the Na-bl value, indeed all of the effect of sex that is not an interaction with thiazide (or a time-related effect) should be reflected already in the Na-bl value. So, would not including the Na-bl term take away from S and change the interpretation of S even though it is not apparent from the equation?

Comment: @Erik I've added a bit to the question to show how you can pursue these scenarios yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, @EdM has provided an excellent answer, from which I would conclude:

Q1: Yes, in reality this is partly true, but formally it is not conventional to call this an interaction.

Q2: If Q1 is (partly) true this affects the interpretation of the interaction term in model 2, since a difference in baseline sodium between men and women is assumed.

The solution to these problems is Model 3.

@EdM also recommends using other types of modeling, although Q1 and Q2 is in that case still relevant.